# Coded UI Test PC\Server Spec Requirement

Tags: optimization, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests, automated-tests

I've been developing Coded UI Tests for a few months now, and have optimized them as much as my knowledge allows. I found some performance issues in regards to running time of the tests.

Currently I have 91 tests, each one of them is quite small and use multiple UI Maps. The time taken to run each tests varies from 1 to 5 minutes, some tests run over 20 minutes. I've watched few of them run, and have noticed that it takes a while for a test to find UI controllers (sometimes it doesn't).

I suppose there are two questions here:

1) Is there an optimal requirements (RAM, HD Space, CPU, etc) for a PC\Server to get best running time results?

2) Is there a way to optimize the Coded UI Tests to improve running time?

Comment: That's why you use a build/test server :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my question by Jack Zhai - MSFT can be found on [MSDN Forum - Optimizing Coded UI Tests And PC\Server Spec Requirement](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstest/thread/7ff0ee7a-0ee7-4c39-a158-23332e7e9e59)